# VBA: How to format different parts of textbox text differently?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to update the text in a specific textbox in a large number of spreadsheets. Some of the text in the textbox needs to be formatted differently from some of the other text. In VBA, how can I give separate parts of the textbox's text different formatting?

Comment: What do you mean by different formatting?  You can use formulas within the textbox to format numbers to % or currency using the =Text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is by accessing the `Characters` collection. This allows you to apply specific formats to different character ranges:

```
Sub tbformats()

Dim tb As Shape

Set tb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes(1)

'Apply bold to the first 10 characters:
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10).Font.Bold = True

'Apply italic to characters 3-5
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(3, 5).Font.Italic = True

' make the last 5 characters red:
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(44, 5).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How can I find out the correct shape number of my textbox? Is it visible in design mode, properties in excel? I can see the name of it.